# Laravel: How to add a field to a collection while looping through

Tags: php, laravel

After a database query, I have a variable `$orderProducts` which when I `print_r` it, it looks like this below.  I am trying to add a field to it (but not save it) before the frontend consumes it.  I am trying to loop through it like this:

```
$orderProducts = Order::with('customer', 'orderProducts.inventory_id')->find(260);

foreach ($orderProducts as $orderProduct) {
   $orderProduct->scanned = "N/A";
}
```

I keep getting the `attempt to assign property of non-object error` though.  Am I approaching this wrong?

***$orderProducts***

```
=> App\Models\Order {#1856
     id: 260,
     customer_id: 36,
     orderProducts: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1871
       all: [
        App\Models\OrderProduct {#1877
           id: 361,
           order_id: 260,
           product_id: 13,
           inventory_id: 223,
        },
        App\Models\OrderProduct {#1877
           id: 361,
           order_id: 260,
           product_id: 13,
           inventory_id: 223,
        },
        App\Models\OrderProduct {#1877
           id: 361,
           order_id: 260,
           product_id: 13,
           inventory_id: 223,
        },
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why the second loop?

Comment: You also might want to check out the `map` and `transform` methods if you're using Collections https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-map

Comment: please post the code where you retrive $orderProducts

Comment: @Berto99 sure -- adding above.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see from here

```
$orderProducts = Order::with('customer', 'orderProducts.variant')->find(260);
```

`$orderProducts` is the order itself and not the products associated to that order; instead you might do something like this:

```
$order = Order::with('customer', 'orderProducts.variant')->find(260);
$orderProducts = $order->orderProducts;
foreach ($orderProducts as $orderProduct) { ... }
```